# k-nn algorithm does not detect digits correctly/perfectly

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, knn

I have learned coding, image processing, OpenCV, c++ and visual studio for one month, and I am in trouble solving a problem. I need help and shed some light.

I have tried the code from this [website](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.nl/2012/06/digit-recognition-with-opencv.html) to detect digits with opencv library, but from 7 digits that are detected, only 3 digits are corrects. What parameters should be changed? In addition, detection start from the right bottom to the left up, shouldn't be detected from the upper left to right? what should I change?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to [formulate your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as precise as possible and preferably include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Others are then much better able to help you with your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use his code and ressources, it should be alright but if you test his code on another image with different numbers and typo, you could give a try to this [image](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/digits.png) that is used in this [sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/digits.py) (Python).

You need to replace his train data by these one:

```
// Loading digit models
HOGDescriptor h(Size(20, 20), Size(10, 10), Size(5, 5), Size(5, 5), 9);
std::vector<float> hdata;
Mat data(Size(324, 5000), CV_32FC1);
Mat responses(Size(1, 5000), CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        h.compute(digits(Rect(j * 20, i * 20, 20, 20)), hdata);
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < hdata.size(); k++) {
            data.at<float>(i * 100 + j, k) = hdata[k];
        }
        responses.at<float>(i * 100 + j, 0) = (float)floor(i / 5.0);
    }
}
KNearest knearest(data, responses);
```

In my case, I use HOG features as it represent way better the digits. Here, digit is the image I quoted above. And to match:

```
Mat sample(Size(324, 1), CV_32FC1);
h.compute(digit, hdata);
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < hdata.size(); k++) {
    sample.at<float>(0, k) = hdata[k];
}
Mat results, neighborResponses, dists;
cout << "Recognised: " << knearest.find_nearest(sample, 7, results, neighborResponses, dists) << endl;
```

If you need to detect black letters on white background, you will need to revert samples:

```
digit = 255 - digit;
```

I have never tried, but you could also used these [OpenCV functions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/text.html) for text detection and recognition. It could be simpler with better results.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @tom
I'll try it. actually i'm mechanical engineering, but my final project force me to fall in this line and I walk like a kindergartner. Thanks for ur help